# Json A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type… »

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

i'm traying to display a list of competitions contained in my data base , but it strikes me each time this error:

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator`2[jTableSampleDatabaseLayer.Hik.JTable.Models.Concour,VB$AnonymousType_2`8[System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.DateTime,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.String,System.Int32]]`' on type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[jTableSampleDatabaseLayer.Hik.JTable.Models.Concour]``'.

here is my code in vb  :

```
Dim x As jTableSampleDatabaseLayer.totofootEntities = _
         New jTableSampleDatabaseLayer.totofootEntities
Dim dataSource = New MemoryDataSource()
Dim liste As List(Of Concour) = x.Concours.ToList()

dataSource.Concours.AddRange(liste)   

''ajout
Try
    Dim concours = dataSource.Concours
    Return Json(New With { _
        Key .Result = "OK", _
        Key .Records = concours _
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

Catch ex As Exception
    Return Json(New With { _
        Key .Result = "ERROR", _
        Key .Message = ex.Message _
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Try
```

How can I avoid this error ?

I've tried to change the code  in order to avoid this error

now i don't get anymore the error but i'm getting  the result with all the attribute are equal to null and the same number of registration in my DB

> {"Result":"OK","Records":[{"numero_concours":null,"numero_etape":0,"numero_type":null,"numero_nature":null,"titre_concours":null,"date_de_sortie":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","nbre_matchs":0,"nbre_rangs":0,"Etape":null,"Nature":null,"Type":null,"Primes":[],"Rangs":[],"Recettes":[],"Rencontres":[]},{"numero_concours":null,"numero_etape":0,"numero_type":null,"numero_nature":null,"titre_concours":null,"date_de_sortie":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","nbre_matchs":0,"nbre_rangs":0,"Etape":null,"Nature":null,"Type":null,"Primes":[],"Rangs":[],"Recettes":[],"Rencontres":[]}]}``'.

the new code :

```
Dim x As jTableSampleDatabaseLayer.totofootEntities = New jTableSampleDatabaseLayer.totofootEntities
        Dim dataSource = New MemoryDataSource()
        Dim liste As List(Of Concour) = x.Concours.ToList()
        dataSource.Concours.AddRange(liste.Select(Function(p) New Concour))


        ''ajout
        Try

                     Dim concours = dataSource.Concours
            Return Json(New With {Key .Result = "OK", Key .Records = concours}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

        Catch ex As Exception

            Return Json(New With {Key .Result = "ERROR", Key .Message = ex.Message}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

        End Try
```

Comment: you would have to provide information how `Concour` is designed
(paste the code of your model)

Comment: the hole model or just the class Concour ??

Comment: the types that are being deserialized to create a Concour object